# BigQuery - Find the size of a Column

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to find the size of a column in bigquery?

I know there is an announcement regarding the `information_schema` that will have column size as well. But not sure when it'll be available.

So any possible way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate size of the column from it's [type size](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data):

> - INT64/INTEGER   = 8 bytes
> - FLOAT64/FLOAT   = 8 bytes
> - NUMERIC = 16 bytes
> - BOOL/BOOLEAN    = 1 byte
> - STRING  = 2 bytes + the UTF-8 encoded string size
> - BYTES   = 2 bytes + the number of bytes in the value
> - DATE    = 8 bytes
> - DATETIME    = 8 bytes
> - TIME    = 8 bytes
> - TIMESTAMP   = 8 bytes
> - STRUCT/RECORD   = 0 bytes + the size of the contained fields
> - GEOGRAPHY   = 16 bytes + 24 bytes * the number of vertices in the geography type (you can verify the number of vertices using the
>   ST_NumPoints function) Null values for any data type are calculated as
>   0 bytes.
>
> A repeated column is stored as an array, and the size is calculated
> based on the number of values. For example, an integer column (INT64)
> that is repeated (ARRAY) and contains 4 entries is calculated
> as 32 bytes (4 entries x 8 bytes).

Also you probably can do:

```
SELECT column_name FROM myDataset.myTable
```

and BigQuery will show how much data it processed.

Comment: string 2 bytes - is this for whole values in a cell or 1 character = 2 bytes?

Comment: it is `UTF-8 encoded string size` + `2 bytes of overhead`

Comment: For example size of string "Hello world" will be 13 bytes = 2 bytes + 11 bytes (UTF-8 encoded string size)